# Steamworld Dig stuck in Vectron

Tags: steamworld-dig

I'm playing Steamworld Dig on PC.  I've dropped down from the Old World into what I think is Vectron.  I'm in a big room with four tall pillars in it.  My drill and pickaxe don't seem to work on any of the metal blocks.  I don't have a teleporter to get back to the surface.  How do I get out of this room?

[image: Where I'm stuck at]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There should be a block on the left pillar you can dig through.**

Dig through the pillar, then head down and enter the door to your right to reach a new area. Dig through the blocks on your right, and there will be a steam pipe you can use to travel back to the surface.